# How to refresh an ASP.NET page on a button click?

Tags: asp.net

On a grid view I have added a button. And when I click the button, I am changing the status from 0 to 1 and then I want to refresh the  page on button click. Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Why you are changing 0 t0 1?. Please check is EnableAutoPostBack is set false for that button. I hope the aspx button will do postback if we click on that , provided no javascript which return false

Comment: paste the html. I think you need to add template coloum and assign the button click event for that. Sharing your code will help to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```html
      public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string odabir = Request.Form["unos"];
            TempData["odabir"] = odabir;
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult prikaz() {
            string putanja = TempData["odabir"].ToString();
            string xmlPutanja = @"C:\Users\BAJAGA\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\mvc\andrijamvc\" + putanja + ".xml";
            List <raspored> raspored = new List<raspored>();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xmlPutanja);
            foreach (XmlNode cvor in doc.SelectNodes("/skola/Raspored"))
            {
                raspored.Add(new raspored
                {
                    rb = cvor["Rbr"].InnerText,
                    dan = cvor["DanUNedelji"].InnerText,
                    predmets = cvor["Predmet"].InnerText
                }
                );
            }
            return View(raspored);
        }

    }
}
@*@{
    ViewBag.Title = "prikaz";
}
@Html.ActionLink("nesto","Index","Home")
<h2>prikaz</h2>
<table border="20">
    <tr>
        <th>Redni br</th>
        <th>Ponedeljak</th>
        <th>Utorak</th>
        <th>Sreda</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (andrijamvc.Models.raspored rp in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@rp.rb</td>
           <td>@rp.predmets</td> 
        </tr>
    }
    
</table>*@
@*@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Html.ActionLink("Prikaz", "prikaz", "home");
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","home")){
<h2>Index</h2>
<form>
Unesi ime fajla:<input type="text" name="unos" />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
}*@
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this in the Grid Properties

```
OnDataBound ="Gridview_Bond"
```

and in the code Behind -

```
protected void Gridview_Bond(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Gridview.DataBind();
       Page.DataBind()

    }
```

Comment: Page.DataBind() is a bad practise. Use databind to the control only. Page.DataBind() will results a performance issue. And your answer is also not a solution for question.

Comment: Read the question..if he wants a page refresh..then there are 2 options..ether Redirect to the same page or Databind..if you have an answer try helping him instead of promoting comments !

Comment: I asked him to share the code. Redirecting to the page will gives him a new page. Let him share the code. I think a post back which was occured when a asp button clicks refresh the page. So I asked to share his html.